# IndexOf() is not working if there is some accent characters in it

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, combobox, dropdown

I have datatable(dtblCostCategory) which has the following values which i use it in the dropdown. And i have saved some data after selecting the value from the dropdown. When i load the same page again the selected value is not being shown instead the first values is shown in dropdown.

```
        dsOtherDetails   

        CostCategory |  typeId  |  itemCount
        ----------------------------------------
          Softwaré   |    3     |     15

        dtblCostCategory

                CostCategory |  typeId    
               ----------------------------
                Electronics  |    1
                Groceries    |    2
                Softwaré     |    3


                cboCategory.DataSource = dtblCostCategory
                cboCategory.DataTextField = dtblCostCategory.Columns(1).ToString
                cboCategory.DataValueField = dtblCostCategory.Columns(0).ToString
                cboCategory.DataBind()

                Dim lstItem As New ListItem
                lstItem.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Trim(CStr(dsOthersDetails.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("CostCategory"))))
                lstItem.Value = Server.HtmlEncode(CStr(dsOthersDetails.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("typeId")))
                cboCategory.SelectedIndex = cboCategory.Items.IndexOf(lstItem)
```

In the above code I have used indexOf to get the selected index by comparing the values from two tables. As there is accent in category (Softwaré) the indexOf is not working properly. Is there way where I can get selected index ignoring the accents so that the drop down will have correct selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [**FindByValue()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbyvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
cboCategory.SelectedIndex = cboCategory.Items.IndexOf(cboCategory.Items.FindByValue(lstItem.Value));
```